# Having source code for third party javascript libraries available whilst debugging

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, angular-cli, source-maps

I would like to know whether it is possible to have third-party javascript libraries' source code available whilst debugging.

FYI, I use npm/nodejs and the angular CLI (which itself relies on Webpack).

Example libraries (together with their source languages) that I would like to have available during debugging are:

- Angular 2 (typescript)
- RxJS (typescript)

I guess what I want to achieve is related to configuring source maps.

Any comment or guidance welcome.

**edit**: Can someone please advise how to configure the angular CLI in order to have angular and RxJS typescript sources available whilst debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement lena's answer and as of **@angular/cli** version's **6.1** is it now possible to output source maps for vendor libraries using the following syntax:

```
ng serve --source-map --vendor-source-map
```

It also works for the `ng build` command.

See also: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/07/27/angular-cli-6.1/

It is then possible to debug third-party libraries using an IDE or the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to be able to set breakpoints in source files while debugging, you need sourcemaps. But this is not the thing that can be configured in the IDE, you need to set up your build tools accordingly. The only thing that should be configured on the IDE end is the run configuration - you might need to specify Remote URL mappings for your project directories

Comment: Thanks for your input. I now understand it is more related to the build tool than the IDE. I am going to edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Hi lena: could you please direct me to relevant documentation/tutorials on how to set up my build tools/sourcemaps configuration in order to have the third-party libraries typescript sources available whilst debugging? I am really stuck here...

Comment: as far as I can see, angular2 .ts sources are not included when you install angular with npm... So, as they are not available locally, they can't be debugged. RJx .ts sources are installed, but not included in webpack bundle built by angular-cli

Comment: That's a pity... Do you know of any way to circumvent this issue? Perhaps by using webpack directly without the angular-cli?

Comment: of course, you can create your custom webpack configuration and use it for building your project. see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that debugging an app with rxjs/angular typescript sources is possible by using webpack directly?

Comment: I found a relevant link here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/#enabling-source-maps